# Flash Builder not recognizing certain keywords

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, undefined, starling-framework

I am trying to follow this tutorial

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/starting-with-starling/starting-with-starling-welcome-screen/

When I try to make the Assets.as class (which starts at around 7 mins) certain keywords are not being recognized by FB. Specifically Dictionary, Texture, and Bitmap. Hears the code...

```
   private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();   
   public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
   {
   if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
   {
   var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
   gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
   }
   return gameTextures[name];
```

I've closely followed the tutorial series up until this point yet I am still getting these errors.

Call to possibly undefined method for Dictionary
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Texture, Dictionary, and Bitmap
Access to possibly undefined property: Texture

I'd appreciate any help I can get fixing this, thank you.

Comment: Have you set up your Flex Project correctly? Is the Flex SDK added to the build path?

Comment: @dgesang Could be wrong, but I suspect the issue might be that those are Flash lib classes rather than Flex SDK classes. You'd think it'd still be able to add imports automatically for those too, but I seem to recall some instances where it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to import the named classes. Before you can use a class from the framework, you have to import it into your class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display3D.textures.Texture;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public class Assets
    {
        private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();   

        public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
        {
            if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
            {
                var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
                gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitMap(bitmap);
            }
            return gameTextures[name];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in Flash Builder you can type `CTRL + SHIFT + O` (`CMD + SHIFT + O` on Mac OS) to clean imports. This will add any required import statement and ask you when there is a conflict (such as with Texture). It will remove any unnecessary imports as well.

When typing the name of a class in your code, you can press`CTRL + SPACE` for auto-completion. The import for the selected class is then made automatically too.

Comment: That was it! Thanks, however, it is still not recognizing "fromBitmap" as a method. If the solution is to add another import statement, how do I know which one to add?

Comment: Find whatever you need in the AsDocs online, and that'll show you the package path you need in your import.

Comment: The imports I showed in my example may not be the correct ones, and I can't access the tutorial you are referring to right now. In other words, maybe `import flash.display3D.textures.Texture` is not the correct import as there is no method `fromBitMap()` for this class.

Comment: I think the `Texture` class you need to import is part of the starling framework which I don't know.

Comment: BRILLIANT explanation duTr!, you've saved my ass. As you suspected, your import statements were all correct, except for the textures one, which in starling is "import starling.textures.Texture;"

Comment: Also, in FB you can type ctrl+shift+O to "clean imports". it will make any needed import statement and ask you when there is a conflict (such as with Texture).